# Spec deprecates `document.registerElement`?

Tags: javascript, document, mozilla

[It seems like the spec has deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) `document.registerElement`.

If this is the case, is there a polyfill for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you point to says the spec was changed to use `customElements.define()`, not that anything changed in Firefox.

As far as I can tell, `registerElement` is only available in Firefox as an experimental implementation (disabled by default), which was not updated to track the spec (support the `.define()` method) as of v57.

The polyfill for Web Components v1 (which is the version with `customElements.define()`) is currently at https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements